Removing phone number validation from Odoo
I´m using Odoo Enterprise v17 with mexican localization
I did an integration with Yeastar, a cloud PBX, this integration allows Odoo to create a record of the call as long as Yeastar recognize the phone number, the issue is that the PBX doesn´t recognize a number when it has the area code (+52) and it has spaces, and Odoo, automatically sets the phone and mobile number as +52 XXX XXX XXXX
I have tried to remove this validation, but it hasn't worked and it gives me an error code about restriction violation. I attempted to use a server action/automated action with the following structure:
I tried with an action server/automated action with the next structure:
Trigger: When you update the contact record
When you update: Phone number record
Execute the next code:
partner_name = record.name.replace(" ", "")
env['res.partner'].create({'name': partner_name})

I also tried to remove the validation deleting the Validation number and mexican localization modules but it causes me issues in other modules
How could I fix this? I hope someone could help me to resolve this
Greetings
